# Can 使劲 only be used for physical effort?

Tags: usage, difference

Can 使劲 (put in effort, strain at) only be used for physical effort? If no, how does its usage differ from 尽量?

Comment: Q easily answered by jukuu, its 100 samples for 使劲 all seem to be of the physical effort type (at least 1-20 and 91-100), re 尽量 see any dictionary, e.g. bkrs: 1) to the best of one's ability 2) (drink/eat) to the full
大家尽量吃饱。 Please eat until you are completely satiated.reach the highest level ... also see jukuu's 100 samples

Comment: Thanks, I did not know jukuu. On linedict, there are examples which suggest that it can also be used to describe non-physical effort, for example: 通过使劲攒钱，你能...

Comment: linedict  getting more comprehensive,
like the defunct nciku?

Comment: 使劲 can be used metaphorically. E.g. 如果你不使劲，别人也帮不了你。"If you don't try hard, no one can do it for you."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

使 = utilize/ apply

劲 = force / power

'**使劲**' as a verb means '**apply force**' ; as an adverb, it means  '**forcefully**';  Since 'forcefully' is an adverb that modifies action verbs,  it is mainly be used for describing physical effort.

For example: 使劲打(forcefully hit), 使劲拉(forcefully pull)

> how does its usage differ from 尽量?

- **使劲** is an adverb for '**forcefully**'
- **尽量** is an adverb for '**to the greatest extent / as far as possible**'.

For example: '尽量不让人知道' (go to the greatest extent not letting people know)

> *'使劲' and '尽量' are not very similar in meaning*

May be you were thinking of '尽力' (with all of one's strength) which can be used to describe physical effort, similar to '使劲' .

For example: '尽力打' (hit with all your might),  '尽力拉' (pull with full strength)

*In this sense, '使劲' and '尽力' are very similar.*

But 尽力 can also be used metaphorically for 'do one's best' or 'try one's best'

For example: '尽力忍笑' (do one's best not to laugh)

> Finally, '**用力**' (用= utilize/ use) (力 = force/strength) is synonym to '**使劲**'
>
> **出力** (出 = output /use) (力 = force/strength) is also a synonym